# how to conditionally display controls in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to hide/show some controls in cshtml based on what is selected in a dropdown list. I want to be able hide/show these sections before the value of the dropdown list is sent back to model and saved. How do I do this? I looked at these questions but had no luck 
[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231558/how-to-call-javascript-in-mvc3-pattern)
[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443263/mvc3-razor-call-javascript-function-from-view)

```
@model Models.EmployerModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
<div>
<p class="validateTips">
    Enter the new employment details.</p>
<fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <b>Employment Type:</b></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("EmploymentTypeDrp")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <b>Job Title:</b></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JobTitle, new { Value = @Model.JobTitle })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

So what I need is that based on what is selected in EmploymentTypeDrp, Job Title be visible or not. I have a JQuery bit to update the model based on new information.

Comment: You need javascrpt/jquery to respond to client side events (handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and show/hide the elements). But showing/hiding them does not change what is posted back to the controller so not sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Side note: remove `new { Value = @Model.JobTitle }` - the value is already set by the `TextBoxFor()` method and you should never try and override the `value` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this

Your view

```
@model Models.EmployerModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
<div>
<p class="validateTips">
    Enter the new employment details.</p>
<fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <b>Employment Type:</b></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                     @Html.DropDownList("EmploymentTypeDrp", new List<SelectListItem>

             {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Admin", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="HR", Value = "0" }
             }) // I just hard coded the departments here                
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <b>Job Title:</b></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JobTitle, new { Value = @Model.JobTitle })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

In the script section of your view you can use `.change()` event  as suggested by **@Stephen Muecke**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#EmploymentTypeDrp').on('change', function (e) {

        var selectValue = this.value;
        if (selectValue == "Admin") {
            $("#JobTitle").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#JobTitle").hide();
        }

    });
});
</script>
```